# How to convert a database to xml file via php in case of joining two or more tables?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I want to convert my wordpress database to xml code using php, there are lot's of codes for this issue but none of them works for joining tables.
I'm using the php code below but it doesn't work because when I join tables I can't define root element so the tree structure is missing

```
  $config['mysql_host']="localhost";
  $config['mysql_user']="user";
  $config['mysql_pass']="pass";
  $config['db_name']="name";
  $config['table_name']="tbl1";

  mysql_connect($config['mysql_host'],$config['mysql_user'],$config['mysql_pass']);
  mysql_select_db($config['db_name']) or die("unable to select database");
  $xml          = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"  ?>";
  $root_element = $config['table_name']."s"; //users
  $xml         .= "<$root_element>";

  //select all item intable
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl1 join tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.id";

 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 if (!$result) {
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($result_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
      $xml .= "<".$config['table_name'].">";

      //loop through each key,value pair in row
      foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
      {
     //$key holds the table column name
         $xml .= "<$key>";

          //embed the SQL data in a CDATA element to avoid XML entity issues
          $xml .= "<![CDATA[$value]]>";

         //and close the element
         $xml .= "</$key>";
       }

      $xml.="</".$config['table_name'].">";
   }
}

//close the root element
$xml .= "</$root_element>";

//send the xml header to the browser
header ('Content-Type:text/xml; default_charset=utf-8;');

//output the XML data
echo $xml;
```

Is it possibe at all? How can I do that?
Any advice much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Two immediate issues: 1) do not concatenate strings to build an XML as PHP maintains [DOMDocument methods](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php): `createElement()`, `appendChild`, `setAttribute`. 2) do not use the deprecated mysql_* functions which has been entirely [removed in PHP 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7).

Comment: Also, what is your source data and desired output? We cannot help if you provide no roadmap but simply code that can mean *anything*?